# $f$ differentiable function such that $f(n)=n\forall n\in \mathbb Z$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $f(n)=n$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z$ then  $\begin{align} 1.\ lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty \\2.\  f \ is \ unbounded \\3.\  f(\mathbb R)=\mathbb R \\4. \  \exists x_n\in (n,n+1) \ such \ that \ f'(x_n)=1  \end{align}$.

$\textbf{Which are the correct?}$

$\textbf{My attempts:}$
$1,2,4$ are correct .

Because:
(1)If, $x\in \mathbb Z$ then we are done!. Now take, $x\in (n,n+1)$, as $x\to \infty \implies n\to \infty$, since $f$ continuous so, $f(n)\to \infty \implies f(x)\to \infty$.

(2) By (1) we can say (2) is correct.

(4) Take the interval $[n,n+1]$, since $f$ is differentiable so by Lagranges MVT $\exists x\in (n,n+1)$ such that $\frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(n+1)-n}=f'(x_n)$. So, we are done!.

But (3) I could not prove or disprove. Can anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint for $3$:  Pick $x\in \mathbb R$ and let $n\in \mathbb Z $ be such that $n≤x≤n+1$.  Then $f(n)≤x≤f(n+1)$.

Comment: $\lim f(x)$ need not exist

Comment: Note:  your argument for $1$ doesn't say anything.  Suppose, for instance, that $f(x)=0$ if $x=n+\frac 12$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: A concrete counterexample to (1) could be $f(x) = x \cos 2\pi x$.

Comment: @Troposphere Yes, thanks I get it.

Comment: @lulu OK! Thanks for your hints for (3). Trying to prove it.

Comment: I don't understand.  It is perfectly possible to define a continuous function that is the identity on integers and $0$ on the half intgers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments $1.$ need not be true , 
For $3.$ Hint: Use the intermediate value theorem since if $f$ differentiable then its continuous .

Comment: Thanks! Just a small question: do I have to edit my post correctly? Actually, I am new here!!

Comment: @Aritra No you should not edit your post as other users may benefit from learning about the error and the comments will become obsolete